# how to check if there are waiting messages in a callback queue?

Tags: ros, messages, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The test case is the following: i receive images from a camera through a callback, and I want to run a loop of processing until a new image arrive. Is there any function that can tell me if there are new messages in the queue? The pseudocode would look like this (i'm looking for new_imagemsg()):

```
void imagecb(imagemsg)
{
  while(!new_imagemsg())
  {
    optimize(imagemsg);
  }
  return;
}
```

I tried the following:

```
void imagecb(imagemsg)
{
  while(static_cast<ros::CallbackQueue*>(nh->getCallbackQueue())->isEmpty())
  {
    optimize(imagemsg);
  }
  return;
}
```

But it looks like the function [isEmpty()](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html#a750d7e58bdacab3041913c0929a44142) always returns false when called from inside a callback, which makes me think that the callback is removed once the callback function finishes instead of when it enters. Unfortunately it looks like [CallbackQueue](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html) doesn't have a getSize function ( i would like to check if the size is bigger than one).

Any other ideas? [clearing](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1CallbackQueue.html#ab960789600b6a6d775249347c234019a) the queue from inside a callback function doesn't seem to work either, apart from being kind of hacky.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9838/how-to-check-if-there-are-waiting-messages-in-a-callback-queue?/) by [Javier Romero](https://answers.ros.org/users/466/javier-romero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The callback queues do not have this functionality.  You'll need to clear the queue and build your own which you can track.  If you use the boost shared pointer callbacks you can do this with only pointers and thus relatively efficiently.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I never used them, but [CallbackQueues](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#CallbackQueue::callAvailable.28.29_and_callOne.28.29) sound like they might help you.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier Romero](https://answers.ros.org/users/466/javier-romero/) on 2011-04-29**:
I tried it, didn't work, so I edited my question.