# Peek at the message queue for a ROS2 topic subscriber in a callback

Tags: ros2, c++, msg-subscriber

I'm sure this facility was in ROS1 (although [this post suggests it wasn't](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/31328/35292)) but I cannot find it in ROS2. Basically in my subscription callback I want something like this pseudocode:

```
Node::subscriber_callback()
    process_message()
    cache_message()
    if this->message_queue_length() == 0
        send_cached_messages()
```

My issue is I'm connecting to a service that works best with message batches, and my topic is getting messages fast enough that I could make batches, but conversely I don't want to delay things if nothing is waiting.

Of course, I could set a timer and send the cached messages when I detect a lull in processing, but it would be simpler to do it all within the single callback.